# Is there a parallel implementation of GBM in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, parallel-processing, gbm

I use the `gbm` library in R and I would like to use all my CPU to fit a model.

```
gbm.fit(x, y,
        offset = NULL,
        misc = NULL,...
```

Comment: `gbm` can be used in parallel on its own. It has an `n.cores` argument that makes it run in parallel. Check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf)

Comment: @LyzandeR The `n.cores` argument parallelizes across cross-validation folds, not for fitting a single model (which I think is what OP is asking for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, both [h2o](http://h2o.ai) and [xgboost](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/xgboost/index.html) have this.

For [h2o](http://h2o.ai), see  e.g. [this blog post of theirs from 2013](http://h2o.ai/blog/2013/10/building-distributed-gbm-h2o/) from which I quote

> At 0xdata we build state-of-the-art distributed algorithms - and recently we embarked on building GBM, and algorithm notorious for being impossible to parallelize much less distribute. We built the algorithm shown in Elements of Statistical Learning II, Trevor Hastie, Robert Tibshirani, and Jerome Friedman on page 387 (shown at the bottom of this post). Most of the algorithm is straightforward “small” math, but step 2.b.ii says “Fit a regression tree to the targets….”, i.e. fit a regression tree in the middle of the inner loop, for targets that change with each outer loop. This is where we decided to distribute/parallelize.
>
> The platform we build on is H2O, and as talked about in the prior blog has an API focused on doing big parallel vector operations - and for GBM (and also Random Forest) we need to do big parallel tree operations. But not really any tree operation; GBM (and RF) constantly build trees - and the work is always at the leaves of a tree, and is about finding the next best split point for the subset of training data that falls into a particular leaf.
>
> The code can be found on our git:
>   http://0xdata.github.io/h2o/

(Edit: The repo now is at https://github.com/h2oai/.)

The other parallel GBM implementation is, I think, in [xgboost](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/xgboost/index.html).  Its Descriptions says

> Extreme Gradient Boosting, which is an efficient implementation of gradient boosting framework. This package is its R interface. The package includes efficient linear model solver and tree learning algorithms. The package can automatically do parallel computation on a single machine which could be more than 10 times faster than existing gradient boosting packages. It supports various objective functions, including regression, classification and ranking. The package is made to be extensible, so that users are also allowed to define their own objectives easily.

Comment: Dirk, from the ``H2O`` blog post link (their code link is dead): "Effectively then, we’re entirely parallel & distributed _within a single tree level_ but not across trees (GBM trees have sequential dependencies) nor within levels of the same tree" (their emphasis). Agreed, one can greatly enhance performance with such clever ideas, but the trees themselves have to be fitted sequentially. My guess is that the ``xgboost`` approach is something similar...

Comment: Still faster than running everything sequentially ...  And their code [is still on GitHub](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3) but I guess repos within move...

Answer (score 4):

Well, there *cannot* be a parallel implementation of GBM **in principle**, neither in R neither nor in any other implementation. And the reason is very simple: the boosting algorithm is by definition **sequential**.

Consider the following, quoted from *[The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/)*, Ch. 10 (Boosting and Additive Trees), pp. 337-339 (emphasis mine):

> A weak classifier is one whose error rate is only slightly better than
>   random guessing. The purpose of boosting is to **sequentially** apply the
>   weak classification algorithm to repeatedly modified versions of the data,
>   thereby producing a **sequence** of weak classifiers Gm(x), m = 1, 2, . . . , M. The predictions from all of them are then combined through a weighted
>   majority vote to produce the final prediction. 
>   [...]
>   Each **successive** classifier is thereby forced to concentrate on those training observations that are missed by previous ones in the sequence.

In a picture (ibid, p. 338):

[image]

In fact, this is frequently noted as a key disadvantage of GBM relative to, say, Random Forest (RF), where the trees are independent and can thus be fitted in parrallel (see the [bigrf](https://github.com/aloysius-lim/bigrf) R package).

Hence, the best you can do, as the commenters above have pinpointed, is to use your excess CPU cores to parallelize the cross-validation process...